# Dynamic rendering for React app on Firebase Hosting via Functions (Python)

Tags: python, reactjs, firebase, flask

I would like that `/story/:storyId` loads `<StoryViewer/>` if it is a real user, or lets Firebase Functions generate an HTML with all the meta-tags if it is a bot.

The code below opens /prerender and, if it is not a bot, where should it redirect it to, so that React picks it up? Sending it again to /story/:storyId would end in an infinite loop.

**firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/story/:storyId",
    "function": "prerender"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

**App.js**

```
<Route path="/story/:storyId" element={<StoryViewer/>} />
```

**main.py**

```
@https_fn.on_request(max_instances=10, timeout_sec=200)
def prerender(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:

    # Define bot user agents
    bot_user_agents = [
      'googlebot',
      'bingbot',
      'whatsapp'
    ]

    def is_bot(user_agent):
        user_agent = user_agent.lower()
        return any(bot in user_agent for bot in bot_user_agents)
    
    if is_bot(req.headers.get('User-Agent', '')):
        response = f"""
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta property="og:image" content="{img_url}">
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        }

        return https_fn.Response(response, headers=headers, status=200, content_type='text/html')
    else:
        headers = {
            'Location': 'https://example.com/story/{}'.format(story_id)
        }
        return https_fn.Response('', headers=headers, status=302)
```